# How to customize image size when using blueimp-gallery lightbox?

Tags: image-size

I'm using http://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/ in a bootstrap environment.
It works with my images but the modal window which shows the full size image is not large enough for me. It takes only  one-third of my screen width.
You can see a live-example here:
http://www.randspringer.de/mannschaftsaufstellungen/1.html

How can I customize the size of the displayed full image?

Answer (score 0):

You could either add

```
data-use-bootstrap-modal="false"
```

to the lightbox container, which displays the images borderless and fullscreen

or adjust the size of the modal according to the bootstrap documentation:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-sizes